# Can I quantize my tensorflow graph for the full version of TF, not tflite?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to quantify my model for use in the full version of tensorflow. And I do not find how to do this (in the official manual for quantization of the model, the model is saved in the format tflite)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only supported quantization scheme in tensorflow is tflite. What do you plan to do with a quantized tensorflow graph? If it is inference only, why not simply use tflite?